# silviomoreto / bootstrap-select [title] attribute

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

There is an attribute [multiple title] according silvio bootstrap-select documentation:

Here is documentation:
[https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

```
<select class="selectpciker" multiple title='Choose one of the following...'>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
</select>
```

It works well! But I need a single select ( not multiple ) . [title] attribute doesn't works without [multiple] attribute.

I didn't find a single title attribute in silvio bootstrap-select documentation.

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: remove `multiple` from select

Comment: Older versions of bootstrap-select are bugged using the `title` attribute without multiple, but the above code works fine without the `multiple` attribute on recent versions (tested on `v1.10`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `data-hidden` attribute on the first option..

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option data-hidden="true">Choose one</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Working demo: http://www.bootply.com/124596

Comment: Thx ! your answer is the best! I'll accept your answer in 2 mins.

Comment: Helped my today since bootstrap-select 1.13.6 disabled html support in the "title" attribute of "<select>" element (Now I can't set icons inside)! I just created a data-hidden option with data-icon=""! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This one is work for me and i wish it's work 100% for you also this is done by the title attribute

```
           <select name="action" id="ActionOnUser" class="selectpicker" title="Action" data-width="auto">
                   <option data-hidden="true"></option>
                   <option value="0">Active</option>
                   <option value="1">Disable</option>
                   <option value="2">Invite Pending</option>
           </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me with the title attribute

```
<select title="Choose One of the following" "class="selectpicker">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I was using an old version of `bootstrap-select`, and after upgrading to v1.10 using just the `title` attribute indeed works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <select class="selectpciker">
    <option>Choose one of the following...</option>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the title to a single bootstrap-select, you should use the data-title attribute.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-title="My Title">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

For more information, see the [bootstrap-select Options section](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me

```
<select multiple data-max-options="1" id="Choice" class="selectpicker form-control" title="What is your choice?" >
<option value="No">No</option>
<option value="Maybe">Maybe</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
```